# How to avoid multiple sprite sheets?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite-sheet, starling-framework

In starling, it's faster if you use BitmapText instead of traditional text. Which is well great except for one issue. Right now the sprite sheet I was making was with a single Fla. I just created the sheet from Flash IDE.

The bitmap text however is generated using a tool like BMFont . Which generates it's own sprite sheet. Now, imagine I have three or four types of texts . Also for some reason I have multiple Sprite sheets of assets.

Changing sprite sheets is not recommended in starling. So I was wondering how can one pack things into a single sprite sheet if you have multiple pngs and accompanying XML's .

Answer (score 1):

I use [texturepacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). It's a commercial tool but the free version can do what you need. It can output a atlas compatible with Starling that will combine your differents sprite sheets.